# How to addClass and/or animate an element inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a widget that other people can load into their html via an iframe.  Everything is working fine to load my custom js file (as the iframe src) into the iframe.  I'm also loading jquery from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js.  My custom js then loads and parses some json at various intervals with $.get() from a server on the same domain as the js file.  I use the json to create html elements that I add inside the iframe.  Again, all of this is working as expected.

The problem that I'm having is that I want to animate the html that I've added inside the iframe.  I'm using the following functions to handle the animation:

```
function embeddedUnMarkAsNew($el) {
    $el.animate({color:"black"}, 500)
}

function embeddedMarkAsNew(timeToMark, $el){
    alert("marking for this time: "+timeToMark)
    //start animation
    $el.animate({color:"red"}, 500);
    //end animation when duration runs
    setTimeout(function() { 
        embeddedUnMarkAsNew($el);
    }, timeToMark)
    return false
}
```

The alert inside of embeddedMarkAsNew() triggers with the proper timeToMark, but the element does not animate.  I've changed the animation to an addClass() just to try it out, and although the class does show up in the inspector as being added, the element itself does not reflect this added class.

I've used this technique on elements outside of iframes.  What is it about doing this inside an iframe that is causing my problems???

Thanks

Comment: ...for color animate you need a library, did you used it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is related to basic browser security.

Cross-origin script cannot be executed in this manner as it would open people up myriad security issues.

What you are trying to do is possible, however, using window.postMessage.

Take a look at the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Basically, you will need an event listener in that page (iframe) that needs to receive a message containing data related to what it needs to do. The containing page, which needs to tell it to do something, calls window.postMessage.

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
```

otherWindow can listen for dispatched messages by executing the following JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ...
}
```

Be careful, though, you will want to check the event.origin to ensure that not just any ol' origin is capable of posting messages in this way.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

jquery not work with color animation by default, to use color animation you need a library such as [bitstorm color animation jquery plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)

To get element from iframe you need .contants() jquery method [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XqtL4/) is demo:

```
function embeddedMarkAsNew(timeToMark, $el) {
    // alert("marking for this time: "+timeToMark)
    //start animation
    $el.animate({
        color: '#FF0000'
        }, 500)
        .delay(timeToMark)
        .animate({color: "#000000"},500);
    return false
}

function demo_fill_iframe() {
        var iframe=$('#iframe').contents().find('body');
        iframe.append($('<div id="test">').text('TEXT'));
}
//create div in iframe
demo_fill_iframe();


//run function!
embeddedMarkAsNew(10000,$('#iframe').contents().find('#test'));
embeddedMarkAsNew(1000,$('#test2'));
​
```

as you see nothing changed to animate inside iframe.
Please also note that I used `delay()` instead of calling subfunction that have the following advantage - `delay` will wait 1st animation finish and then run second one if all you need is to change colors back, `delay` is the best choice. Also I would you to exchange order of parameters in function, so you will be able to skip second option and set it as default:

```
function embeddedMarkAsNew($el,timeToMark,AnimationTime) {
    //default time is 1000
    timeToMark=timeToMark!==undefined?timeToMark:1000
    AnimationTime=AnimationTime!==undefined?AnimationTime:500;
    //start animation
    $el.animate({
        color: '#FF0000'
        }, AnimationTime)
        .delay(timeToMark)
        .animate({color: "#000000"},AnimationTime);
    return false;
}
```